# How to enable "Sites.Manage.All" delegated permission for an application registered with Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to enable "Sites.Manage.All" delegated permission for one of my application registered with Azure to create new Sharepoint lists with my application.

But I'm getting an error "**Unable to save changes. One or more of the following permission(s) are currently not supported: Sites.Manage.All. Please remove these permission(s) and retry your request. [psMwx]**"

I'm using an account who is the owner of the application to add Delegated  permissions to api to run the app on the context of signed in user, still I get this error, not sure what I'm missing in here.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your Azure AD APP is for **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**.

[image: personal Microsoft accounts]

But based on [Sites permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#sites-permissions), Sites.Manage.All Delegated permission is not supported for personal Microsoft Account. It's a limitation of Microsoft Graph.
[image: Sites.Manage.All]

So there are 2 methods to solve this issue:

- Register a new Azure AD app which is **Accounts in this organizational
  directory only (Dev Chat Support only - Single tenant)** or
  **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)**.
- Modify the existing Azure AD app Manifest by replacing
  "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" with "AzureADMyOrg" or
  "AzureADMultipleOrgs", and Modifying the value of
  "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" from "2" to "1".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. Not specific to "Sites.Manage.All" delegated permission, but in fact with any new permissions I tried to add.

This was for an app registration that has been there for a while, with mixed delegated and application permissions for Microsoft Graph, and with the flag **"Authentication > Default client type > Treat application as a public client"** set to **"Yes"**.

After some trial and error attempts I managed to pinpoint the problem to this flag. If it's set to "Yes", the registration won't allow any "application" permissions, only "delegated".

Since my current app registration already has the flag set and also has some application permissions, I can't change it anymore.
Every time I try to save something, it triggers the validation and fails.

This is a new thing because it worked fine up until a few days ago.
I think this might be a bug on Microsoft side and I hope they'll fix it soon.

Unfortunately, I need the application to be treated as a public client because I'm using the resource owner password credential (ROPC) flow.
For now I'm considering split my app registration into two: one for delegated permissions and one for application permissions, and use each one on my client accordingly.

Far from ideal…

Answer (score 0):

It should have selected Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant).

I was able to fix the problem by going into the app manifest and changing signInAudience to AzureADMultipleOrgs

```
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",
```